# Can I plug directly a 0-10Vdc dimmer current for LED to a SMD4051?

Tags: multiplexer, dimmer

I have a LED dimmer which generates a 0-10 Vdc, can I connect it directly to a SMD4051 such as [the Onsemi (on Reichelt)](https://secure.reichelt.com/fr/fr/multiplexeur-d-multiplexeur-analogique-8-1-3--18-v-so-16-smd-4051-p18474.html?&nbc=1) ([documentation](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mc14051b-d.pdf))?

If I understand well, the plexed current must be below the DC supply, which must be between 3 and 18 Vdc. So if one of my 8 input is between 0 and 10 Vdc, I must provide 10-18 Vdc as supply: is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

You may want to stay away from the 18V maximum (for reliability) and give it a bit more than the 10V minimum (in case the actual maximum exceeds the 10V), for example 12VDC or 15VDC.

Comment: Sounds good. Is using this multiplex with this supply current (say 12Vdc) compatible with receiving current from temperature sensors Pt 100ohms (https://secure.reichelt.com/fr/fr/puce-de-capteur-de-temp-rature-en-platine-c-bl-100-ohms-pca-1-2003-1-p85056.html?&nbc=1) ? I mean do I impair the precision in any way ?

Comment: I guess you know the resistance of the switches in the multiplexer is very high so you need some Kelvin-like  techniques to avoid excessive errors in such an application. The resistance is lower at higher supply voltages.